# Querying Matching User Data With Drupal and mySQL

Tags: 7, database

I'm using Drupal 7 with the current mySQL version. I've got a custom profile field table that includes an entity_id (which corresponds to the user id) and a value field, which has one of a number of text strings that users can select as a personal interest. The number of strings a user can select for their profile is variable.

I need to query out the logged in user's list of interests, then query out any users who have any matching interests and their user id. I have a query/subquery script that basically works:

```
$subquery = db_select('table')                          
    ->fields('table', array('value'))
    ->condition('table.entity_id', $user->uid, '=');

$query = db_select('table', 't')
    ->fields('p', array('entity_id', 'value'))
    ->condition('value', $subquery, 'IN')
    ->condition('entity_id', $user->uid, '<>')
    ->orderBy('entity_id', 'ASC')
    ->groupBy('entity_id');
$result = $query->execute();
```

This query returns multiple rows:

entity_id     value

entity_id     value

entity_id     value

entity_id     value

What I need is:

entity_id     value, value, value, value

entity_id     value, value

entity_id     value, value, value

I've searched and searched and cannot figure out how to do this. Can anyone help?